# How can I order a map by value efficiently?

Tags: c++, stl, sorting

Consider a `std::map<K,V>`. I want to re-order the map by value profiting by an appropriate container `std::C<V*>` or `std::C<V&>`, in a way that no copies of values are done to store the elements in C. Furthermore, elements in C must be sorted according to the result of `int f(V&)` applied to each element. Despite my efforts I could not find an appropriate C and an enough efficient way to build it. Do you have any solution? A small example would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't clear.  You want your new container to contain a bunch of pointers to the values of a map, and to be sorted?

Comment: Is the destination container a sequence container or associative?  (vector vs map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems simple enough.

```
std::map<K,V> src;
int f(V&) {return 0;}

V* get_second(std::pair<const K,V> &r) {return &(r.second);} //transformation
bool pred(V* l, V* r) { return f(*l)<f(*r); }   //sorting predicate

std::vector<V*> dest(src.size());  //make destination big enough
std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), dest.begin(), get_second); //transformcopy
std::sort(dest.begin(), dest.end(), pred); //sort
```

Unless you meant C is supposed to be another map:

```
std::pair<K,V*> shallow_pair(std::pair<const K,V> &r) 
{return std::pair<K,V*>(r.first, &(r.second));}

std::map<K, V*> dest2;
std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), 
               std::inserter(dest2,dest2.end()), shallow_pair);
```

http://ideone.com/bBoXq

This requires the previous map to remain in scope *longer* than `dest`, and have no pairs removed until `dest` is destructed.  Otherwise `src` will need to have been holding smart pointers of some sort.

Comment: +1: Looks correct.  Could you use `std::transform` and `std::back_inserter` instead of the explicit loop?

Comment: Probably, but I don't feel like they add much.  I probably would if the standard library had `get_pair_first` and `get_pair_second` unary functions already.

Comment: Come on, you're using c++11 already: `[](pair<K,V> &v) { return &v.second }` :-)

Comment: which is faster between the vector and map in your opinion?

Comment: @Martin: it depends on what you're doing with it.

Comment: @krynr: MSVC doesn't support lamdas, so I avoid them.  Other than that, done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::reference_wrapper`, like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

#include <prettyprint.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, std::reference_wrapper<T> const & rw)
{
  return o << rw.get();
}

int main()
{
  std::map<int, std::string> m { { 1, "hello"}, { 2, "aardvark" } };
  std::cout << m << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> v;
  for (auto & p : m) v.emplace_back(p.second);
  std::cout << v << std::endl;

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<std::string>); // or your own predicate
  std::cout << v << std::endl;

  v.front().get() = "world";
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

```
[(1, hello), (2, aardvark)]
[hello, aardvark]
[aardvark, hello]
[(1, hello), (2, world)]
```

Comment: using nonstandard libraries?  I guess that's fair.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `refcomp`, is that not something custom?

Comment: @MooingDuck: I removed that ghastly thing, thanks to the input in the other question.

Comment: an explicit `std::less<std::string>` is a good idea for a workaround, but he wanted it `sorted according to the result of int f(V&)...`

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh OK, I didn't see that. Yes, then you'll need the predicate anyway. I'll just add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using multiple containers to represent multiple views into the same dataset. The trouble with this approach is in keeping the containers synchronized and avoiding dangling pointer issues. [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) was made for just this purpose. A `boost::multi_index` container stores only one copy of each element, but allows you to access the elements via several *indices*.

Example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/global_fun.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

typedef std::string Key;
typedef int Value;

struct Record
{
    Record(const Key& key, Value value) : key(key), value(value) {}
    Key key;
    Value value;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Record& rec)
{
    os << rec.key << " " << rec.value << "\n";
    return os;
}

inline int sortFunc(const Record& rec) {return -rec.value;}

struct ByNumber{}; // tag

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
  Record,
  bmi::indexed_by<
    // sort by key like a std::map
    bmi::ordered_unique< bmi::member<Record, Key, &Record::key> >,

    // sort by less<int> on free function sortFunc(const Record&)
    bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<ByNumber>, 
                            bmi::global_fun<const Record&, int, &sortFunc> >
  > 
> RecordSet;

typedef RecordSet::index<ByNumber>::type RecordsByNumber;

int main()
{
    RecordSet rs;
    rs.insert(Record("alpha", -1));
    rs.insert(Record("charlie", -2));
    rs.insert(Record("bravo", -3));

    RecordsByNumber& byNum = rs.get<ByNumber>();

    std::ostream_iterator<Record> osit(std::cout);

    std::cout << "Records sorted by key:\n";
    std::copy(rs.begin(), rs.end(), osit);

    std::cout << "\nRecords sorted by sortFunc(const Record&):\n";
    std::copy(byNum.begin(), byNum.end(), osit);
}
```

Result:

```
Records sorted by key:
alpha -1
bravo -3
charlie -2

Records sorted by sortFunc(const Record&):
alpha -1
charlie -2
bravo -3
```

Answer (score 0):

The place I'd start is to:

- look at [Boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)
- create ordering from V -> K via a comparator function object which evaluates f(V&) the way you suggested. (e.g. as in [`std::map<K,V,C>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) where C is a comparator class)

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
std::set<boost::shared_ptr<V>, compfunc>
```

where compfunc is a functor which takes two shared_ptr objects and applies the logic in your function?

Excuse the formatting, not good on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (untested pseudo code):

```
V* g(pair<K,V> &v) { return &v.second; }
bool cmp(V* a, V* b) { return f(*a) < f(*b); }

map<K,V> map;
vector<V*> vec;
vec.reserve(map.size());
transform(map.begin(), map.end(), back_inserter(vec), g);
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), cmp);
```