# C++ failed template argument deduction. why?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>
Ref<Iterator<T> > GetFilterIterator(Ref<Iterator<T> > i, boost::function<bool(T)> pred) {
    return new FilterIterator<T>(i, pred);
}


Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> > x = GetFilterIterator(worms(), &CWorm::getLocal);
```

And `worms()` returns a `Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> Ref>` and there is `bool CWorm::getLocal();` (which is a member function). And:

```
template<typename T> struct Ref {
     // ...
};

template<typename T> struct Iterator {
     // ...
};
```

This will fail to deduce the template argument:

> Iter.h:272:27: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction [3]

Why?

If I call it with the specified template argument, i.e. `GetFilterIterator<CWorm*>(worms(), &CWorm::getLocal)`, it doesn't complain. I wonder why it cannot deduce the template argument like this. And can I make it different somehow so that it would be able to automatically deduce the type?

Comment: What type is `Iterator<CWorm*>::Ref`?

Comment: [Related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677072/overload-resolution-failure-when-streaming-object-via-implicit-conversion-to-str)

Comment: `bool CWorm::getLocal();` cannot match `boost::function<bool(T)>`, because it does not take an argument.

Comment: As a member function `getLocal` would work as `function<bool(CWorm*)>`

Comment: @bames53: Only if it is wrapped using `std::mem_fun`.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Is that specific to boost::function? Because it's not required with std::function.

Comment: @bames53: You're right, now that you mention it, i remember reading it somewhere - guess I am wrong then.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513050/why-can-template-instances-not-be-deduced-in-stdreference-wrappers/8513174#8513174) should answer your question too.

Comment: @Xeo: How? It speaks about implicit type conversion, but `Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> Ref>` doesn't need a type conversion to be matched against `Ref<Iterator<T> >`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from Xeo to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513050/why-can-template-instances-not-be-deduced-in-stdreference-wrappers/8513174#8513174) about that implicit type conversions are not allowed when deducing template arguments, I wondered wether the second parameter might cause problems here. I thought that it would do the type deduction from left to right and once the type is deducted, it is not a problem anymore (for the function pointer to `boost::function` cast).

It seems I was wrong and this was exactly the problem.

Another version of the same thing avoids the problem:

```
template<typename T>
struct PartialFuncWrapper {
    ::Ref<Iterator<T> > i;
    PartialFuncWrapper(::Ref<Iterator<T> > _i) : i(_i) {}
    typename Iterator<T>::Ref operator()(boost::function<bool(T)> pred) {
        return new FilterIterator<T>(i, pred);      
    }
};

template<typename T>
PartialFuncWrapper<T> GetFilterIterator(::Ref<Iterator<T> > i) {
    return PartialFuncWrapper<T>(i);
}
```

Then I can write:

```
Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> > x = GetFilterIterator(worms())(&CWorm::getLocal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `typname Iterator<T>::Ref` for the type of the first parameter in the `GetFilterIterator` template declaration? If so, that is not a deducible context for template type parameters.

Consider:

```
template<>
struct Iterator<Foo> {
    typedef int Ref;
};
template<>
struct Iterator<Bar> {
    typedef int Ref;
};

GetFilterIterator(int(0),f);
```

Both `Iterator<Foo>::Ref` and `Iterator<Bar>::Ref` match the parameter passed to GetFilterIterator, an int. Which one should it pick? C++ disallows deducing template types from parameters like the one you've declared.

---

With the update to your question it looks like you do mean `::Ref<Iterator<T> >`. I think that should be deducible then, and since the typedef `Iterator<CWorm*>::Ref` is `::Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> >` it seems like it should be able to deduce `T`. I'm not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot deduce the template arguments because fitting to the parameters would mean a non-trivial conversion - first to `Iterator<T>` and then to `Ref<Iterator<T> >` which both require user-defined conversions. Also, directly converting the member function pointer to boost::function is similarly non-trivial for the compiler.

IBM has a [list of supported template parameter deductions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Ftemplate_argument_deduction.htm).

If you want your template arguments to be deduced automatically, you have to provide wrapper methods:

```
template <typename T>
Ref<Iterator<T> > makeIteratorRef(T val)  {
    return Ref<Iterator<T> >(Iterator<T>(val));
}

template <typename T>
boost::function<bool (T)> makeFn(bool (T::*fn) () const)  {
    boost::function<bool (T)> res = boost::bind(fn, _1);    
    return res;
}

...

Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> > x = GetFilterIterator(makeIteratorRef(worms()), makeFn(&CWorm::getLocal));
```

This way the compiler is capable of deducing the template parameters because no conversions are necessary.

By the way, I think you are overcomplicating simple things:

```
for (auto it = worms().begin(); it != worms().end(); ++it)
  if (it->isLocal()) { 
    // Do something
  }
```

This code is way more readable in C++ and even though it might not be as general it hardly makes the code worse.

Comment: There is no conversion involved. It just needs to match `Ref<Iterator<T> >` with `Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> >`. I always thought that wouldn't be a problem (and I also don't see why it is; I'm quite sure I have seen similar stuff elsewhere). Also, this already determines `T`, so the `boost::function` stuff doesn't matter anymore then.

Comment: Ah, did you overread this? "`worms()` returns a `Ref<Iterator<CWorm*> Ref>`".

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that point. Then the problem lies in conversion to boost::function - you will need the makeFn wrapper or some alternative to it.