# Type conversion from std::complex<MyType> to std::complex<double>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a class `MyType` that implements a user-defined arithmetic type. This class provides the following conversion operator

```
struct MyType 
{ ...
  operator double()
  { 
    return to_double(); // This converts my type to a double value
  }
... };
```

Using this class as follows works fine:

```
double d = MyType(1);
```

However, using this class as type within std::complex, e.g.

```
#include <complex>
std::complex<double> c = std::complex<MyType>(1,1);
```

fails with the following compiler error:

```
error: conversion from 'std::complex<MyType>' to non-scalar type 'std::complex<double>' requested
```

Any help to solve this problem is appreciated.

Matthias

Answer (score 3):

> The specializations `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, and `std::complex<long double>` are LiteralTypes for representing and manipulating complex numbers.
>
> The effect of instantiating the template complex for any other type is unspecified.

So `std::complex<MyType>` is "problematic"...

Ignoring that part,

whereas [`std::complex<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex) has generic converting constructor, specialization `std::complex<double>` only provide conversions from other floating complex versions.

But [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%3D) allows generic conversion for all versions (Only Msvc accepts the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/Ya9cGR) though).

You have to provide your own (explicit/named) conversion function:

```
std::complex<double> to_complex_double(std::complex<MyType>& c)
{
#if 0
     std::complex<double> res;
     res = c; // gcc/clang doesn't accept that.
     return res;
#else
     return {c.real(), c.imag()};
#endif
}
```

Comment: I re-read doc, and `std::complex<MyType>` is mostly unspecified...

Comment: I can implement a `to_complex_double` conversion function but that does not solve my problem, I guess. I want to use this inside the Eigen library which, internally, makes use of `return static_cast<NewType>(x);`, whereby `x` is `const std::complex<MyType>&` and `NewType` is `std::complex<double>`. Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Even if `std::complex<MyType>` was not unspecified, the primary template doesn't allow that. specialize `std::complex<MyType>` would allow to have expected behavior (unsure if it is allowed to specialize `std::complex<MyType>` though)

Comment: And from [what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513417/what-can-and-cant-i-specialize-in-the-std-namespace/8513497#8513497), `std::complex<MyType>` cannot be specialized.

Answer (score 0):

Does this (not particularly elegant) workaround help?

```
std::complex<MyType> dummy(1,1);
std::complex<double> c1(
    static_cast<double>(dummy.real()), static_cast<double>(dummy.imag()));
```

I tried all kinds of different constructors and assignment operators of `std::complex` but did not find a more "implicit" way of converting.

I think this is related:
[Why doesn't a conversion function work with std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17645045/2546289)