# Overloading operator== for const std::reference_wrapper in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, operator-overloading, reference-wrapper

I can't figure out how to get a `std::string` reference into an `std::unordered_map` using a `std::reference_wrapper`.  Per the following link I understand I need to overload `operator==`.

[Why can template instances not be deduced in `std::reference_wrapper`s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513050/why-can-template-instances-not-be-deduced-in-stdreference-wrappers)

However, I can't figure out how to write `operator==` such that it will take a **const** `std::reference_wrapper`.  If the wrapper were not **const** it would not be a problem.

Using a char instead of `std::string` works fine (doesn't require overloading `operator==`).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

bool operator==(const std::reference_wrapper<std::string> lhs,
                const std::reference_wrapper<std::string> rhs)
{
    return std::equal_to<std::string>()(lhs.get(), rhs.get());
}

int main(){
    char        chr('a');
    std::string str("b");
    int         num(1);

    // this works (char)
    std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<char>, int, std::hash<char>> charMap;
    std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<char>, int> charPair(chr , num);
    charMap.insert(charPair);
    std::cout << "charMap works.  Output: " << charMap[chr] << std::endl;

    // does not work (std::string)
    std::unordered_map<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>, int, std::hash<std::string>> stringMap;
    std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>, int> stringPair(str , num);
    stringMap.insert(stringPair);  // compile error
}
```

Compile error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const std::reference_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘const std::reference_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’)
       { return __x == __y; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot provide your own overload for `operator==` for non-user-defined types. That is, at best, undefined behavior. However, you don't need to do that here. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) has *five* template parameters:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator< std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class unordered_map;
```

See the 4th one? That's what you want. You need to provide a function to compare. Luckily, you can use std::hash and std::equal_to like this:

```
std::unordered_map<
    std::reference_wrapper<std::string>,
    int,
    std::hash<std::string>,
    std::equal_to<std::string>
> stringMap;
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution. Unfortunately, `std::reference_wrapper` doesn't specify `operator==` (it would be easy to just forward it to `operator==` of the underlying type) and doesn't provide a hashing method, either. So one has to be always explicit, when creating an `unordered_map` or `unordered_set` with these.